# How to remove android permissions when wrapping html5 app using Cocoonjs

Tags: android, html, android-permissions, construct-2

Every time when I use Cocoonjs Cloud services to convert a HTML5 app to Android app, it automatically adds all the unnecessary android permissions. It makes users confused when downloading app. In fact, all unnecessary permissions such as access to phone book, access the internet, wifi access, location, etc. will be added to the manifest file.

Is there any way I can remove those permissions. Actually, I am using Construct 2 to build the application, then wrap it using ludei cloud services. After that, I received an unsigned apk file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a proper answer but the [official doc](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/809/how-to-export-to-android-with-crosswalk) recommends crosswalk instead of Cocoonjs and it seems that crosswalk will let you choose which permissions to use.